# jquery is not working on ie

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, click, internet-explorer-9

The following code works on Chrome, Firefox and Safari however it is not working on IE9. Does anyone have any idea?

**How the code should work is:**
when mouse is over a #calendar then the '.day' will be clickable. '.day' background will also change color if mouse hover over it. Once '.day' is clicked, a jquery-ui dialog box will pop up to take in a value.

**In IE9**:
'.day' is not clickable. '.day' background color also does not change when mouse hover over it. Nothing happens.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').mouseout(function() {
    $('#calendar .calendar .day').unbind('click');
});


$('#calendar').mouseover(function() {       
    $('#calendar .calendar .day').bind('click', function(){
        day_num = $(this).find('.day_num').html();
        $('#dialog-form').dialog("open");
    });
}); 


$(function() {  

    $('#dialog-form')
        .attr('title', 'Number')
        .dialog({ 
            autoOpen: false,
            closeOnEscape: true, 
            draggable: false, 
            resizable: false,
            height: 180,
            width: 450,
            show: 'fade', 
            modal: true, 
            buttons: { 
                'Ok': function() {
                    var spinner = $("#spinner").spinner();
                    day_data = (spinner.spinner( "value" ) );

                    if(day_data !=null){

                        $.ajax({
                            url: window.location,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {
                                day: day_num,
                                data: day_data
                            },
                            success: function(msg){
                                location.reload();
                            }
                        }).error (function() {
                            alert('an error occured');
                        });     
                    }
                },

                Cancel: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }

        });
}
```

Comment: You don't need a document.ready function inside another document.ready function

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `#calendar1` should just be `#calendar`.

Although, may I suggest this simplification of the event handling?

```
$("#calendar").on("click",function(evt) {
    day_num = $(evt.target).closest(".day").find(".day_num").html();
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
});
```

This is all you need. None of that overcomplicated `mouseover`/`mouseout` stuff.

Comment: oops sorry! #calendar1 should be #calendar - thats a typo while posting the question.

Comment: I need the overcomplicated mouseover/mouseout to differentiate the multiple calendars I am having. So unfortunately still need it. Any ideas why it is not working on IE?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it will work for you

```
$('#calendar').mouseover(function() {       
        $('#calendar1 .calendar .day').bind('click', function(){
            day_num = $(this).find('.day_num').html();
            $('#dialog-form').dialog("open");
        });
    });
```

above code required with in the document ready

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').mouseout(function() {
        $('#calendar .calendar .day').unbind('click');
    });


    $('#calendar').mouseover(function() {       
        $('#calendar1 .calendar .day').bind('click', function(){
            day_num = $(this).find('.day_num').html();
            $('#dialog-form').dialog("open");
        });
    }); 

});

$(function() {  

    $('#dialog-form')
        .attr('title', 'Number')
        .dialog({ 
            autoOpen: false,
            closeOnEscape: true, 
            draggable: false, 
            resizable: false,
            height: 180,
            width: 450,
            show: 'fade', 
            modal: true, 
            buttons: { 
                'Ok': function() {
                    var spinner = $("#spinner").spinner();
                    day_data = (spinner.spinner( "value" ) );

                    if(day_data !=null){

                        $.ajax({
                            url: window.location,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {
                                day: day_num,
                                data: day_data
                            },
                            success: function(msg){
                                location.reload();
                            }
                        }).error (function() {
                            alert('an error occured');
                        });     
                    }
                },

                Cancel: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }

        });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Hey Naveen thanks for that but it is still not working on IE =S